# Capistrano + SVN, Merging Branches/Tags and Deploying

Tags: svn, capistrano

We are finding that merging using tortise SVN is slow and cumbersome, we've also recently started using capistrano (capify) to deploy to development.

Is there a way to merge revisions to a branch and automatically deploy to another environment if needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had also problems with branches merging and long deploys on svn, it speed up after switching to git.

Regarding automatic merging and deploy that might be hard task, maybe easier would be using another branch with:

```
cap -S branch=my_branch deploy
```